# Granting website privileges to access cross-domain iframe content

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am looking to create a browser written in HTML using [AsYouWish](https://github.com/brettz9/asyouwish/). (AsYouWish exposes the privileged Firefox Addons SDK to regular websites, subject to user approval for each privilege requested by the site; note, however, that this question doesn't really require knowledge of AsYouWish, just the SDK or XPCOM APIs.)

My [demo](https://github.com/brettz9/asyouwish/tree/master/demos/requestPrivs-browser-in-browser-demo.html) is able to make a cross-domain request and add the text to the iframe using srcdoc, but due apparently to security restrictions, I can't get a `contentDocument` out of the iframe (as when I try to change the src on an iframe instead, as per [this demo](https://github.com/brettz9/asyouwish/blob/master/demos/requestPrivs-browser-in-browser-demo-no-srcdoc.html)).

Is there some kind of means (content-proxy, security policy, or whatever it may be called) in the Addons SDK (or XPCOM) I might use to escalate my website's privileges to introspect the (cross-domain) `contentDocument` here (so I can listen in from the parent for page location changes in the iframe and thus build my own browser history with back and forward buttons, etc.)?

**UPDATE**: Since I understand remote XUL has been disabled, I am thinking that perhaps my only (albeit awkward) solution might be to detect a request by a site for DOM privileges, and if granted by the user, reload the page within a privileged iframe of a chrome:// document (since as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Displaying_web_content_in_an_extension_without_security_issues the inner iframe will be granted privileges in this case unless restricted and thus presumably the privileged iframe should be able to reach into its own (cross-domain) iframes). I wish I could allow it access into its cross-domain child frames without access being able to come out of it up to the chrome level, but I can probably live with that since granting cross-domain iframe access is already a very high level privilege.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: No, except that I had not been aware of `window.frameElement` which might help me in my stated goals, but no progress as far as my main question. Nw (formerly node-webkit) has some promising looking abilities toward building something fairly easily as far as a privileged iframe parent: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Mini-browser-in-iframe

Comment: Another possibility is to use this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Cross_Domain_Content_Scripts#Content_Permissions_and_unsafeWindow

Comment: I've filed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1254435 to hopefully get wildcard support since the cross-domain content script is currently limited to a whitelist approach.